# How to force PHP to work with the LOCAL watch

Tags: php

How can I force PHP to work with my LOCAL time machine watch?

If im working LOCALY and the time is 15:15 for example, I want that whenever I will run the code: `date('H:i')` it will output "15:15". If the LOCAL time on other machine/server will be 16:15, it will show 16:15 and so on.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set your local timezone in php datetime function. then it will always return your timezone timestamp.

Comment: Do you mean each visitor will see the time in their own timezone?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually set the timezone for the entire php page:

https://www.php.net/datetime.settimezone.php